# tsconfig.app.json not found when deploying to App Engine

Tags: ios, angular, google-app-engine, angular-universal

I'm trying to deploy an Angular-cli 6 Universal app to App Engine for the first time. I'm getting the error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/src/tsconfig.app.json'
```

I don't have any issues building or testing the app. What determines the path? I've looked at the migration guide that describes changes from angular-cli.json to angular.json, but I can't find the solution.

tsconfig.json (root project folder)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json (in /src under the root)

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine", "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

angular.json has this reference

```
"tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I was excluding some files in app.yaml that I should not have excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If the `tsconfig.app.json` not found, you can check your local CLI using the command `ng version` :

[image]

If your global Angular CLI version  is greater than your local version, please install the your global Angular CLI version using this command: `npm i @angular/cli@xx.xx.xx` . You can check the right command in this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions .